I have Ubuntu 24.04 installed on my desktop computer. My windows 10 is still installed but I'm trying to delete both Ubuntu and windows 10
PS I want to switch them out for windows 11 I only installed Ubuntu because my admin had broke on my windows 10

Does this answer your question? How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?

You don't remove an unwanted OS, you just install the new OS over it... This applies if you have a dual-boot system (be with with 2, 3 or any number of OSes).

@guiverc how do i do that through on Ubuntu 20.4

Boot the OS you want to install (ie. windows 11 in your case as I understand it) and use the Erase disk and install option (where that option can have different wording depending on the installer you use; but we don't support windows on this Ubuntu Q&A site)   Ubuntu is not involved if you're replacing it with another OS, you do it all from the OS you're installing.

@guiverc im sorry for using ask Ubuntu but i thought ether was good but i thought it was more suitable to use because of troubles i had with windows not helping me before thank you for your help

Just install the new OS (in your case Windows 11), letting the installer use the entire drive and reformat it for the new OS. It's the same in case of any OS installation, regardless of what you had previously installed on the computer, however the actual wording in the OS installer may differ. You have to figure it out, it should not be difficult, as installing the new OS on the entire drive is the most basic and straightforward installation option in almost every OS, and it's usually the default.
